# How to save data into new rows in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, save

I have a JSON like this.

```
{
    "productName":"soap",
    "pQty":10,
    "price" : 100,
    "customerList":[
        {
            "name":"dasun",
            "email":"lakmal@gmail.com",
            "gender":"male"
        },
        {
            "name":"BM",
            "email":"BM@gmail.com",
            "gender":"male"
        }
        ]
}
```

I want to save this data into two separet tables called **Product** and **Customer** which having 1 to many relationship same as JSON`s appears.

I tried to save data using @OnetoMany but I couldn't. So I created entities like this.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "product_id",updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long pId;
    private String productName;
    private int pQty;
    private int price;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
}
```

Customer Entity

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "customer_id",updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long custId;

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String gender;
}
```

My Rest Controller

```
@PostMapping(path = "/save/product",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Iterable<Product> saveProduct(@RequestBody Product product){
        Iterable<Product> response = automantionApiService.saveProduct(product);
        return response;
    }
```

My Repositories

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long> {
}

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer,Long> {
}
```

This is where I want your attention. here what I`m doing is iterating request and trying to create new data rows as same as the request and save to DB.

```
@Override
    public Iterable<Product> saveProduct(Product product) {
        Product product1 = new com.adl.dte.core.model.Product();
        product1.setProductName(product.getProductName());
        product1.setPQty(product.getPQty());
        product1.setPrice(product.getPrice());

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<>();

        if(!product.getCustomerList().isEmpty()){
            product.getCustomerList().forEach( listOfCust ->{
                customer.setName(listOfCust.getName());
                customer.setEmail(listOfCust.getEmail());
                customer.setGender(listOfCust.getGender());
                customerRepository.save(customer);
                product1.setCustomer(customer);
                productRepository.save(product1);

            });
        }
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }
```

But my problem is only the last customer will be saved to the Db who named "BM". same as the response like this.

```
[
    {
        "productName": "soap",
        "price": 100,
        "customer": {
            "custId": 5,
            "name": "BM",
            "email": "BM@gmail.com",
            "gender": "male"
        },
        "pqty": 0,
        "pid": 6
    }
]
```

My target is to save each and every customer to the customer table and mapped with Person. 
What I got wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: "*I tried to save data using @OnetoMany but I couldn't.*" - Why not? For the JSON you have shown, `@OneToMany` is the right association. `@ManyToOne` on the `Product` is definitively wrong since each `Product` then can only have one `Customer`.

Comment: The product entity has only one 'customer' and you set it explicitly 'product1.setCustomer(customer);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, fix the relationship as follow

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "product_id",updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long pId;
    private String productName;
    private int pQty;
    private int price;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Customer> customerList;
}
```

Product entity will change as below

@Data

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "customer_id",updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long custId;

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String gender;

    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;
}
```

then change your `saveProduct` as below

```
@Override
public Iterable<Product> saveProduct(Product product) {
    Product product1 = new com.adl.dte.core.model.Product();
    product1.setProductName(product.getProductName());
    product1.setPQty(product.getPQty());
    product1.setPrice(product.getPrice());
    product1.setCustomerList(product.getCustomerList());

    product.getCustomerList().forEach(cust -> cust.setProduct(product1));
    productRepository.save(product);
    return productRepository.findAll();
}
```

Comment: Sir in Customer entity how it would be look like?

Comment: private Product product annotated as ManytoOne?

Comment: Sir cust.setProduct(product)) should cust.setProduct(product1))?

Comment: Another thing, there is no cust.setProduct() method as well.

Comment: @dasun_001 Right, it should have been `cust.setProduct(product1))`. Also, it's a fair assumption that you will create the missing setter method in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems:

First, define a Customer list (`List<Customer> customers`) in your Product entity bean. Then add customers to it with the addCustomer method.

Also use for each customer a own new Customer object and don't use one Customer and update the values.

Saving each Customer is not necessary. Saving the Product object/entity should be enough.

The values are saved to the database when the transaction is committed and closed.  Spring handles this for you.

Comment: I'm facing a bit difficulty in figuring out what you are saying . can you just edit the code if you don't mind pls.